# foreach record in database show in user control c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml

I am trying to show data from a database to a user control I created which consists of TexBoxes and buttons. So far I am   able to pull data from the database and show it on my user control but it only show the last record so only one record eventhough I know there is another record that exists. I want it to show multiple user controls with the amount of data(records) are in the database.

```
<%
List<ActionGame> actionGame = GameService.GetItems(id);

    foreach (ActionGame GameItem in actionGame)
    {
        textBox1.Text = GameItem.Name;
        textBox2.Text = GameItem.Type;
        textBox3.Text = GameItem.Price;    
    } 
    %>
```

Like is there a way I could re use the user control multiple times or any other way I could show all the records from my database in the user control

Comment: you are overwriting your textbox text every time in loop

Comment: I'm curious to see the implementation of your user control.  That's where the answer lies.

Comment: GetItems basically gets all the records from the database by the Id and puts it in a list so for instance actionGame[0].title would be record 1 and actionGame[1].title would be record 2 its all done through nhibernate mappings

Comment: @user2653531 Is it necessary to use `TextBox` to store result?

Comment: yes It is teboxes in a user control can I re use the user control for each record?

Comment: Yes, you can reuse them - in fact, that is exactly what you are doing, only you are doing it too quickly to be visible. Use [a list of some sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27057404/336648) instead.

Comment: @user2653531 if you want to use the texbox for storing value then tou should create dynamic texboxes as per number of records ..
Like if you have 3 rows of data then create three rows of textboxes(in your case 3 X 3 textboxes).

Comment: Sure but I have a user control for this purpose I know you can re use the user control for each record I just don't know how to go about implementing it. All the user control consists of at the moment is 3 labels and 3 textboxes nothing more

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx)
What you're doing is, that you're always updating the Text Property of the TextBox with the last received data - overwriting the previous data of the record before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but it seems a little awkward to use textboxes for this.

You could just append to each textbox instead of overwriting in each iteration of the loop:

```
// Note: Clear the contents of each textbox before reaching this point 
foreach (ActionGame GameItem in actionGame)
{
    textBox1.Text += GameItem.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox2.Text += GameItem.Type + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox3.Text += GameItem.Price + Environment.NewLine;    
}
```

...but I would imagine this might give a messy result.

I would imagine some kind of list view would be better for your purpose.

Tip: See [the documentation for ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx), and search for some examples that fit your need.

Another option is to use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.100).aspx). That should allow you to create as many textboxes as you need dynamically ([example of usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5(v=vs.100).aspx)).

Comment: This gets the data for all the records but It shows them in the same textbox I want it to show it in separate textboxes

Comment: ...yes, and that is is why I recommend you use a ListView instead. Or perhaps you could use a Repeater (updating my answer with a new link now).

Comment: I need to use texboxes have u much experience with user controls because I know I  can re use the user control (which consists of texboxes for my data) but just don't know how to go about implementing it

Comment: See my last link: It uses a repeater with a header, an item template, and an alternating item template. You probably just need a single item template, where you place your controls. That template will then be repeated for each `GameItem` in `actionGame`. That should help you along.

Answer (score 0):

For normal selects from database a `Datagridview` is very popular as the form of data displayed is exactly the same as in database workbench. What you are doing is replacing text in your Textboxes for each item in the list.